# iPod lyrics hiding things in <> ... workaround?

Tags: ipod, lyrics

I bought a CD, ripped it and copied it to my iPod Touch.  Then I found the lyrics on the internet, confirmed that they're the same as in the album booklet, and pasted them into the lyrics section in iTunes.

Everything's great, except for one track.  It's a collaboration, and in the lyrics, before each section, it says who's doing that part by putting their name in `<>`.  For one artist, it looked fine, but for the other, the line was blank!

What gives?  And what workaround is there to make both artists names appear?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of experimentation, I found a workaround.  The artist whose name wasn't appearing has a name that starts with an ASCII character.  It looks like iOS is trying to be clever, and ignoring anything that looks like it might be an HTML tag, even if it really isn't!

One simple workaround is to put a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (you can copy/paste one from that article) right after the `<`.  Your iPod will no longer assume it's HTML, and it will display just fine!